# Can not start cloudera-scm-server-db because of "The CM is using external DB"

Tags: postgresql, cloudera-cdh

I've updated jdk from 1.8_131 to 1.8_151 for CDH5. So i need to restart the cluster to make it take affect. In the begining i use cloudrea manager web page to restart, but it failed when zookeeper started which is the  first step. Then I made a bad choice which is close cloudrea manager in terminal including kill -9 postgresql process. After that, i could't open the  cloudrea manager web page.

I use following instructions to start the cluster.

```
service cloudera-scm-server-db start
service cloudera-scm-server start
service cloudera-scm-agent start
```

All of them are failed, because `/var/log/cloudera-scm-server` and `/var/log/cloudera-scm-agent` disappear.

So I creat these two files manually also include `dg.log` and `cloudera-scm-agent.log`

At this time, the `server` and `agent` could start. But `server-db` still can not. The next is some details.

> Starting cloudera-scm-server-db (via systemctl):  Job for
>   cloudera-scm-server-db.service failed because the control process
>   exited with error code. See "systemctl status
>   cloudera-scm-server-db.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details

journalctl -xe

> The CM is using external DB. Failed to start embedded DB service, giving up

[service --status-all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDkzy.png)

What i've done:

So, what should i do now? thank you thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above problem had been sovled.

If you open this `/etc/cloudera-scm-server/db.properties` file, which shown as below.

```
# cat /etc/cloudera-scm-server/db.properties

Auto-generated by scm_prepare_database.sh
#
Sat Oct 1 12:19:15 PDT 201
#
com.cloudera.cmf.db.type=postgresql
com.cloudera.cmf.db.host=localhost
com.cloudera.cmf.db.name=scm
com.cloudera.cmf.db.user=scm
com.cloudera.cmf.db.password=TXqEESuhj5
com.cloudera.cmf.db.setupType=EXTERNAL
```

> EXTERNAL is the crux.

In my CDH service, I use embedded postgresql as my server database. But it's not recommended to use by cloudera offical. I'm a new man on Cloudera, so I made a mistake.
I wrongly use a command which only prepared for Cloudera Manager Server external database.

```
/usr/share/cmf/schema/scm_prepare_database.sh postgresql scm scm scm_password
```

The above command can config `db.properties`

As long as you run above command, `com.cloudera.cmf.db.setupType` will be set to `EXTERNAL`(For more details about this, you can find in [*Cloudera docs*](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-2-x/topics/cm_ig_installing_configuring_dbs.html))

The most direct and effective way is to [*reset password of scm*](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-6-x/topics/cm_ig_embed_pstgrs.html).

Then

- update the password
- set Type as EMBEDDED
- make port 7432 listening(you can use `netstat -nltp` to check)

in db.properties.

```
#vim cat /etc/cloudera-scm-server/db.properties
Auto-generated by scm_prepare_database.sh
Sat Oct 1 12:19:15 PDT 201
com.cloudera.cmf.db.type=postgresql
com.cloudera.cmf.db.host=localhost:7432
com.cloudera.cmf.db.name=scm
com.cloudera.cmf.db.user=scm
com.cloudera.cmf.db.password=new_password
com.cloudera.cmf.db.setupType=EMBEDDED
```

Now close all cloudera-scm service and restart in order `server-db`,`server`,`agent`.

If /var/log was cleared wrongly.

You can creat these files such as `/var/log/cloudera-scm-server` and `/var/log/cloudera-scm-agent` manually.

It is noteworthy that you should creat these file by user `cloudera-scm`, otherwise the log can not be written, and you won't find what error happened from log file.